# Trying to make a circuit for a 3D printed lamp

Tags: led

I am trying to figure out a circuit for my 3D printed lamp. I am trying to use a 9V battery to power a 3.2V through hole LED. Would you suggest a buck converter or a switching voltage regulator?

Comment: A buck converter is a switching voltage regulator.

Comment: How big of a lamp? A 9V battery will not power it for very long.

Comment: @Justme Ahhh gotcha

Comment: @rdtsc Not a big lamp. The led I would use would have about 20-60 mA forward current. Would you recommend another power source for a portable lamp?

Comment: You didn't provide many details about your project, but, as it seems that you don't have so much experience with eletctronics, I suggest that the best option for powering a single 3.2V LED would be a bunch of three AA cells, and a current-limiting resistor connected in series with the LED. I don't see any reasons for using a 9V battery just to have those 9V reduced to the LED voltage. And the three AA cells will last more than the 9V batt.

Comment: A household [alkaline 9V battery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nine-volt_battery) typically has a capacity of about 550mAh. That's 0.55A for 1 hour, then it's dead. If 60mA were drawn from it, it will last 550mAh/60mA = 9.1h - and that is assuming 100% conversion efficiency, which it won't be, so expect significantly less. In contrast, [AA alkaline cells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AA_battery#Primary_cells) have a capacity of about 2500mAh.  Those would run 60mA for at most 2500/60 = ~41h.

Comment: I second the recommendation for AAs, also rechargeable AA are common whereas rechargeable 9V are not. If size is a problem and you want something small, you can also use a protected RCR123 lithium ion rechargeable battery, it has an ideal voltage for one white LED and a resistor (3.6V).

Answer (score 1):

9V alkaline batteries are really only best for a select number of extremely low current applications.  They were more useful before efficient voltage converters became ubiquitous and cheap.  Because they are a niche market and 6 small cells crammed into a double casing, you pay a lot for what you get. In addition, you only need 3.2V for your LED.

If you want to use alkaline batteries, 1.5V AAs would be better.

You can use 3 AAs to get 4.5V and use a series resistor to limit current to your LEDs.

How big of a resistor?  Well 4.5V - 3.2V is 1.3V left over that has to be dropped by the resistor.  If the resistor is passing 20 mA,

E = IR so R =E / I = 1.3V / 0.02A = 65 Ohms

P = EI = 1.3V * 0.02A = 26 mW minimum

If the resistor is passing 40 mA

E = IR so R = E / I = 1.3 V / 0.04 A = 32.5 Ohms

P = EI = 1.3 V * 0.04 A = 52 mW minimum

If battery life and consistency of brightness matter a lot, you can use a switching voltage converter to maintain a constant voltage to the LED and resistor, or use a constant current driver and get rid of the resistor for best efficiency.

Answer (score -1):

- If you are doing this just for fun and for a short period, use a voltage divider or potentiometer to power the LED. You will be able to dim or brighten the LED as you rotate the potentiometer
- If you are planning on using the LED for a longer period, I would recommend buying a power supply that outputs 5V, and use a buck converter to output 3.3V. I am almost sure that a 5V would turn on the LED; you need to make sure that the you put in an appropriate resistor in series with the LED.
- If you want to use a battery, buy a buck converter and make sure to look at the efficiency of 90percent. You will not find a buck converter that has an efficiency of 100 percent.

Comment: No, don't use a voltage divider.  Use a single series resistor.  LEDs are current driven devices.  Limit the current and the voltage will take care of itself.

Comment: @JRE Use Potentiometer to dim or brighten the LED; that's all